# Alternative to using ant <modified> selector?

Tags: bash, build, continuous-integration

I'm trying to find an alternative to a helpful piece of functionality provided by ant - [the `<modified>` selector](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#modified).

When specifying a set of files in ant, you can use the `<modified>` selector to only include files whose content has changed since the last time it was run.

> The  selector computes a value for a file, compares that to the value stored in a cache and selects the file if these two values differ.

Is there an existing way of doing this in `bash`? I don't want to use a full blown build tool or similar just to return a list of modified file paths.

Comment: The build tool maintains the data by which you can consider a file to be modified. How do you want to determine what is modified outside that context?

Comment: The ant build tool does so by creating a `cache.properties` file, and writing a line `<file path>=<file content hash>` for each file. It then compares with and updates the file on subsequent builds. I'm wondering if there is an existing tool for doing something similar outside of ant.

Comment: You could use `find` to produce a list of files modified before/after/at a specific time, but you still haven't specified how to determine what that time is.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear - I'd like to keep a cache file, the same way that ant does. I can't rely on file modification times, because the working directory may be recreated (for example when switching branches). I'm envisioning storing a cache file per VCS branch. I figure I could write something to do this using `find` and some hashing command, but I was wondering if anything similar already exists (that isn't part of a full blown build tool).